# Magento: Get product id in php block for available in list.phtml

Tags: list, magento, attributes

I'm trying to get an attribute for it to be listed on list.phtml, the form that is being made is as follows:
I created a module on the Block and created a function which captures the attribute:

```
    protected function getPreOrder()
{
    $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $preOrder = $product->getNewsFromDate();

    $preOrder = substr($preOrder, 0, 10);

    return $preOrder;
}
public function getViewList() 
{
    if(strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) <= strtotime($this->getPreOrder()))
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

However, nothing is returned. I also did this same method to view.phtml and it worked perfectly. That goes for a file before the function getChildHtml() phtml, is not being edited list.phtml

That makes sense to create a loop, but the loop is already list.phtml!

What would be the way?
I thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you debugged your block function to see if the product id is correct and if its loading the model correctly ?? 
Also debug the template list.phtml to check if its correctly loading the block type ?

> get_class($this);

and see what class type is it.

Comment: Hello Meabed,
Yes, the function is loaded into phtml normally.
The function getPreOrder() used for the same purpose in a different block, but this view.phtml used in this case ran smoothly.
My difficulty is getting the product_id, to use for list.phtml, nothing is returned.
It is very strange that since the list is a foreach.

Comment: I tryMage::registry('current_product')->getId() and return

Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object

And I try $_proId = $this->getProduct()->getId(); $_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_proId);

and returns the same thing.

The Class extends from Mage_Core_Block_Template. It's correct?

Why only in list.phtml can not get the product id?

Comment: So this means no product exist in the registry !
Print out the ID you get from the request see if you actually can see it ! echo this ? echo     $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');